# Construir tabela indicando "0" para valor não encontrado Python

Tags: python, pandas, tabela-html

Preciso montar uma tabela de frequência para valores observados versus valores esperados. Porém não estou conseguindo formatar corretamente a indicação da frequência dos dígitos e a inclusão dos valores "0" para dígitos não encontrados.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Empresa':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'],
        'Valor_Empenhado':[520.00,751.00,654.00,781.00,120.00, 551.00,62.00,78.00,77.00,1053.00]}
               
df =pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Empresa','Valor_Empenhado'])

df['first_dig'] =df['Valor_Empenhado'].astype(str).str[:1] #seleção do 1º digito
freq = df.groupby(['first_dig']).size() # frequencia dos digitos

total = freq.sum() # Quantidade total

Po = [None] # proporção observada de cada dígito

for i in freq:

  Po.append(i/total)

Po

Pe = [None,0.301,0.176, 0.125, 0.097, 0.079, 0.067, 0.058, 0.051, 0.046 ] # proporção esperada
dig = range(1,10) # faixa de números procuradas

print('-'*29) # montagem da tabela
print('Digito    Pe          Po')
print('-'*29)
for d in dig:
  print(f'{d:3} {Pe[d]:10,.3f} {Po[d]:11,.3f}')
```

`

```
Está ficando assim:
-----------------------------
Digito    Pe          Po
-----------------------------
  1      0.301       0.200
  2      0.176       0.200
  3      0.125       0.200
  4      0.097       0.400

Mas preciso que fique assim:

Digito    Pe       Po_1º_dig
-----------------------------
  1      0.301       0.200
  2      0.176       0.000
  3      0.125       0.000
  4      0.097       0.000
  5      0.079       0.200
  6      0.067       0.200
  7      0.058       0.400
  8      0.051       0.000
  9      0.046       0.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi, você está querendo aplicar a Lei de Benford (ou o Algoritmo do Ladrão).

Há uma biblioteca não nativa que implementa esse algoritmo:
github.com/milcent/benford_py

### Respondendo a sua questão

##### Substituindo o Hard Code por expressões logarítmicas

Você pode primeiro criar a distribuição de Benford via logaritmo a título de precisão.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

benford_df = pd.DataFrame([(d, np.log10(1 + (1.0 / d))) for d in range(1,10)], columns=['first_dig','distribution'])
```

|  | first_dig | distribution |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0.301030 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.176091 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.124939 |
| 3 | 4 | 0.096910 |
| 4 | 5 | 0.079181 |
| 5 | 6 | 0.066947 |
| 6 | 7 | 0.057992 |
| 7 | 8 | 0.051153 |
| 8 | 9 | 0.045757 |

##### Criando o seu dataframe

```py
data = {'Empresa':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'],
        'Valor_Empenhado':[520.00,751.00,654.00,781.00,120.00, 551.00,62.00,78.00,77.00,1053.00]}
               
df =pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Empresa','Valor_Empenhado'])
```

##### Calculando a sua distribuição

Fiz dois ajustes na sua forma de calcular a distribuição.

1. Assegurei que o dígito seja do tipo `int`
2. Assegurei que o resultado seja um objeto do tipo `DataFrame` e não `Series`

```py
df['first_dig'] =df['Valor_Empenhado'].astype(str).str[:1].astype(int) #seleção do 1º digito
freq = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['first_dig']).size()).reset_index()
freq.columns = ['first_dig','my_distribution']
```

##### Mesclando os dados

Com os dois Dataframes podemos agora mesclá-los usando `how=left` para que os dígitos sem correspondência não desapareçam

```py
benford_df.merge(freq, on='first_dig', how='left').fillna(0)
```

|  | first_dig | distribution | my_distribution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0.301030 | 2.0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.176091 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.124939 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 4 | 0.096910 | 0.0 |
| 4 | 5 | 0.079181 | 2.0 |
| 5 | 6 | 0.066947 | 2.0 |
| 6 | 7 | 0.057992 | 4.0 |
| 7 | 8 | 0.051153 | 0.0 |
| 8 | 9 | 0.045757 | 0.0 |

Bônus: Se quiser plotar essa tabela num gráfico de comparação, dê uma olhada nessa resposta do StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756433/benfords-law-plotting-in-python-3-5-2

Comment: Perfeito, consegui melhorar muito o código com sua dica!